# Whitespace under tabularx in combination with vspace*

Tags: xetex, tabularx, vspace

I am using the tabularx package to create some variable definitions in 3 columns. I am trying to add some space under each line with the \vspace* command. These are created automatically by an algorithm and saved into a tex file.

The problem is that between normal text the space shows ok, but under any tabularx definition the space is huge. I have tried several values for \vspace*: at 0.1ex it seems to nullify the whole whitespace, while at 0.2ex it suddenly jumps to this huge whitespace.

Could someone help me understand why this occurs and how would I have a proper whitespace under my tabularx lines like shown in the picture? I am building with xelatex and xetex.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nopageno}
% Required for mathematics.
% Load currfile early to work around underflow
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{trig}
\usepackage{infwarerr}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{standalone}

% Required for a table that fills the page (e.g description template)
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
%
% required by fontspec so lets precompile to save time later
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontenc}
%
% required by unicode-math so lets precompile to save time later
\usepackage{expl3}[2015/03/01]
\usepackage{ucharcat}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % avoid some warnings
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkGreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

%column definitions for the addDeclaration() function
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.0\baselineskip}\hsize=1.9\hsize}X}                                  %text column
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.0\baselineskip}\hsize=0.75\hsize}X}                             %symbol column
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.0\baselineskip}\hsize=0.35\hsize\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}       %clause column right aligned

%
%Set main font and font for math, use something that is available on windows back to XP
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Set distance from top of page to first float to avoid tables showing in the middle of a new page.
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{\familydefault}

\begin{document}

    \begin{normalsize}
    
    \textbf{\underline{GENERAL DESIGN ATTRIBUTE PROPERTIES}}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    Design attribute: \verb|1:Des1|
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    Calculation method: Bending and in-plane (Sandwich model / Principal stresses)
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    Member type: Two-way slab
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \textbf{\underline{GEOMETRIC PROPERTIES}}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    Reinforcement attribute: \verb|1:WdAmr1|
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Section depth & $h$ = 300 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.2ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Unit width & $b$ = 1000 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Cover to top face & $c_{top}$ = 50 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Cover to bottom face & $c_{bot}$ = 50 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Bar diameter (top x) & $\diameter_{tx}$ = 20 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Bar diameter (top y) & $\diameter_{ty}$ = 20 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Bar diameter (bottom x) & $\diameter_{bx}$ = 20 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Bar diameter (bottom y) & $\diameter_{by}$ = 20 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Spacing (top x) & $s_{xTop}$ = 150 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Spacing (top y) & $s_{yTop}$ = 150 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Spacing (bottom x) & $s_{xBot}$ = 150 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {@{}TSC@{}}
    Spacing (bottom y) & $s_{yBot}$ = 150 mm & \textit{}
    \end{tabularx}
    \vspace*{0.6ex}

    \end{normalsize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is every row here a `tabularx` table on its own? And why are you adding these `\vspace`'s. Perhaps explain in more detail what your endgoal is. Additionally see the `siunitx` package for the propper formatting of values and their units.

Comment: unrelated to spaces but you shouldn't be loading any of these with a current xelatex document xunicode, graphics, trig, tabu, expl3, xparse, fontenc, expl3, ucharcat, fix-cm, filehook,

Comment: Each row is a separate tabularx call because any module that wants to report a variable can call and add this to the tex script. My goal is ultimately to have some spacing between each row like the ones shown in the picture as normal spaces. PS: This is an old codebase which I am updating with minimal tex knowledge, so any input is welcome.

Comment: @Tsaras but a one-row table is not a table, so why use tabularx (or tabular) at all?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the only purpose is to have 3 columns to use so that I can align variable description, value w/ optional units and an optional clause among the various variables declared in the document.

Comment: your tabularx have width \textwidth and so the \vspace is on the next line. You would get a similar space if you ended your lines above with ``\\``. Use `\par\vspace{0.6ex}`  to get a more reliable output.